# Jackson YAML Merge Operator Deserialization Wrong

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I'm using Jackson to serialize and deserialize YAML but I'm encountering a problem with deserializing [merge operator](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html).

For example:

```yaml
- &item001
  boolean: true
  integer: 7
  float: 3.14
- &item002
  boolean: false
- <<: [ *item002, *item001 ]
```

This yaml file isn't deserialized properly with jackson yaml.

This is the code I'm using:

```kotlin
val text = ..... // 
val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()
                .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER))
                .registerKotlinModule()
val list = mapper.readValue<Any>(text)
```

And it outputs basically:

```js
[{"boolean":true,"integer":7, "float": 3.14}, {"boolean": false}, {"<<": 2}]
```

Rather than:

```js
[{"boolean":true,"integer":7, "float": 3.14}, {"boolean": false}, {"boolean":false,"integer":7, "float": 3.14}]
```

It's strange though because Jackson YAML uses SnakeYAML underlying and if I perform the same operation with SnakeYAML it deserializes correctly.

Of course I could switch to SnakeYAML but my project needs both json and yaml converters and Jackson provides me with both.

Any suggestions?